# Django, Error creating user profile when new user registers

Tags: python, django

I am developing a Django website by following a Github repo as mentioned below.

When new user signup, it does not create a profile associated with it, when I try accessing the profile, I got response as

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /accounts/profile/
User has no profile.
```

What might went wrong here ?

The following code snippets are from `users` app of my Django project.

apps.py

```
class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'
    
    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

signals.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    phone = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['address','phone']
```

(git hub repo of following tutorial : https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Django_Blog/11-Pagination/django_project/users),

Comment: There are enough books you can read to learn those things, SO isn't a right place to ask such question. Here's a guideline on how to ask a question properly https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) again. Also, I would say there are not many better courses. Udemy already has some of the best. Just get a book. They should be much more advanced, something you would learn from.

Comment: You should search google for `python web dev paths` Well, as per your choice, you should find out aout `Django` and some fromt end framework like `Bootstrap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the below code `default_app_config = 'myapp.apps.MyappConfig`in `__init__.py` module